# Can we use just <a href="#"> for "back to top" button at bottom of the page?

Tags: xhtml, usability, accessibility

Can we use just `<a href="#">` for "back to top" button at bottom of the page? I think it will work always in all browser. We do need to define any ID .

When we click on this  `<a href="#">` it takes to page top always. or what are other best practices to use "back to top" button.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can and should use that, as that is what it means. There are no other practices for doing a 'back to top' button, and even if there is, they're unnecessarily complicated compared to this.

Comment: `<a href="#">Go to top of page</a>`

Comment: <a href="#" title="Go to top of page" >Go to top of page</a> in a much better way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using just '#' is good. It's not very meaningful for the user.

You don't need to define an extra id just to use it to snap back to the top of the page. It's much better to use an existing element on the page. For example, if you have a logo on top of the page, you can assign the `<img>` tag the id of 'top':

```
<img src="logo.png" id="top">
```

At the bottom of the page, you can then use this element id to go to the top of the page:

```
<a href="#top" title="Go to top of page">Go to top of page</a>
```

This will produce `http://www.mysite.com/#top` which will be more meaningful for your visitors.

Answer (score -1):

The disadvantage of **`href="#"`** is the addition of **`#`** to the URL.
The best practice for “back to top” button is to reload the page using two options:
Empty href:
 **`<a href="">Top of the Page</a>`**
Reload the page to the current file in terms of writing its name, for example:
 **`<a href="filename.html">Top of the Page</a>`** .

Comment: I would say this is the worst option since it reloads the page which is not what you want in this case.